$y\ln y - y = x\ln x - x$ ; How do I write $y$ explicitly as a function of $x$?
I used Desmos and found that $y\ln y - y = x\ln x - x$ can be splited into two functions.
It looks clear that one of them is $y=x$.
However, I am having trouble finding out the second one.
How do I derive it, and how can I prove rigorously that $y\ln y - y = x\ln x - x$ can be split only by these two?
p.s. I am currently a student studying calculus 2, so I would appreciate it if you could make this as easy to understand as possible. Thank you.

Interesting problem. So far you can show from log laws that $(\frac{y}{e})^y = (\frac{x}{e})^x$, and by differentiating you can show that $\frac{dy}{dx} ln(y) = ln(x)$. Not sure where to go from here though

The two parts seem to correspond to the two different real branches of the product log function, which can solve for $y$ here.

No elementary solution.

As other answers show, this function requires the Lambert W function to separate $x$ and $y$ in closed form. However, we can easily find a parametric solution without the Lambert W. This lets us find solution pairs $(x, y)$ and plot the graph if we don't have the Lambert W, or an implicit function solver like Desmos uses.
Clearly, the straight line part of the graph corresponds to the solutions with $y=x$. So we want to find the other solutions where $y \ne x$. The logarithm isn't defined for the argument of $0$, so let's assume that $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$.
Let $y = ux$, with $u \ne 1$, since we don't want the straight line solutions.
Thus
$$ux\log(ux) - ux = x\log(x) - x$$
We can divide by $x$ because it's non-zero.
$$u\log(ux) - u = \log(x) - 1$$
$$u\log(u) + u\log(x) - u = \log(x) - 1$$
$$u\log(u) - u + 1 = \log(x) - u\log(x)$$
$$\log(x)(1-u) = u\log(u) - u + 1$$
Hence
$$\log(x) = \frac{u\log(u) - u + 1}{1-u}$$
That is,
$$x = \exp\left(\frac{u\log(u) - u + 1}{1-u}\right)$$
and
$$y = u\exp\left(\frac{u\log(u) - u + 1}{1-u}\right)$$
So now we can plot the graph, using $0 < u < \infty$. The $u$ values $<1$ give the lower branch, the $u$ values $>1$ give the upper branch. For plotting purposes, it's convenient to use $1/u$ for the upper branch.
Here's a plot, using Sage.

The script can also do the plot using the Lambert W.

Thank you so much!

Similar to the usual parameterization of $x^y=y^x$ by setting $y=rx$.

@marty Yes, it is. I was very happy when I discovered that parameterisation (by myself) a few decades ago. I don't think I'd learned about the Lambert W at that stage, but my memory is a little fuzzy...

This is a really cool trick, I didn't even think about parametrisations. Awesome!

Let $X=x \ln x - x$. Then $y\ln y - y = X$ can be written as $y=\frac{X}{W(X/e)}$, where $W$ is the Lambert W-function (also note the similarity between your plot and the one in the "identities" section).
Due to the properties of $W$, you have to be a bit careful with the branches.
Here, we should use the principal branch ($W_0$) for $0< x < 1$ and $W_{-1}$ for $1<x<e$. Using $\ln W(x)=\ln x - W(x)$, we then find
$$y\ln y-y=\frac{X}{W(X/e)} \left( \ln X - \ln W(X/e) -1\right) = \frac{X}{W(X/e)} \left( \ln X - \ln (X/e) + W(X/e) -1\right) = X,$$
as expected. So, choosing the respective $W$-branch for the region, we can write
$$y = \frac{x\ln x - x}{W([x\ln x - x]/e)}.$$
Here is a plot of the (two!) results

First simplify using log laws
\begin{equation}
\ln(y^y) - \ln(e^y) = \ln(x^x)-\ln(e^x) \\
(\frac{y}{e})^y=(\frac{x}{e})^x
\end{equation}
Now the aim is to solve for $y$ by using the Lambert W function, which states that $W(qe^q)=q$.
\begin{equation}
x\ln(\frac{x}{e}) = y\ln(\frac{y}{e}) \\
\frac{x}{e}\ln(\frac{x}{e}) = \frac{y}{e}\ln(\frac{y}{e}) \\
\frac{x}{e}\ln(\frac{x}{e}) = e^{\ln(y/e)}\ln(\frac{y}{e}) \\
\end{equation}
Apply Lambert W function to both sides of equation. In this case $q = \ln(\frac{y}{e})$
\begin{equation}
W(\frac{x}{e}\ln(\frac{x}{e})) = \ln(\frac{y}{e}) \\
y = e^{W(\frac{x}{e}\ln(\frac{x}{e}))+1}
\end{equation}

Basically, you want distinct values of $x$ and $y$ so that $f(x)=f(y)$ where $f(x)=x\ln x-x$.
Assuming $f(x)=f(y)=t$,
$$\begin{align}
&x\ln x-x=t\\
&\implies \frac{x}{e}\ln{\frac{x}{e}}=\frac{t}{e}\\
&\implies \ln\frac{x}{e}=W_n\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)\\
&\implies x=e\exp\left(W_n\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$
Where $W_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ Lambert-W function.
Thus, your required plot can be realized as the joint parametric plot of  $\left(e\exp\left(W_0\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)\right),e\exp\left(W_{-1}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)\right)\right)$ and $\left(e\exp\left(W_{-1}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)\right),e\exp\left(W_{0}\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)\right)\right)$
This can be rewritten as a piece-wise function:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e\exp\left({W_{0}(\frac{x}{e}\ln{\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)})}\right) & 0< x\leq 1
\\
e\exp\left({W_{-1}(\frac{x}{e}\ln{\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)})}\right) & 1< x< e
\end{cases}$$
SageCell link [Might take long to render]

Better SageCell link, suggested by PM2Ring in the comments.


You can speed up the plot by not plotting so close to zero. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjEEOgjAQRfc9xYQNM6aAxbjsHVi4M4ZUnSJJoU2p0uMbjEt2%5F728%5FI%2DJWOaShFWggeEAnAM6M905pn7Fo4TcbNr5AXPDRCRsu5tWaqcVHWgIzie8WiXBtjcJeObqJIFJgo1mYn2Jb5YwxPHpxpmXP5sl8CP10aTRa0Wiq5eXX%5FE3zIex2G7rMA8FiS9GhzrI&lang=sage

Notice that by doing the substitution $s=x/e$ and $t=y/e$ we get the slightly simpler equation
$$s \log s = r \log r \tag 1$$
As other comments point out, this cannot be solved analytically in closed form, unless we resort to the Lambert W function.
Regarding existence: to show that eq $1$ has one more solution apart from the trivial one ($r=s$), amounts to compute the preimages of the function $f(s) = s \log s$

It's easy to prove that $f(s)$ is decreasing on $(0,s_0)$ and increasing on $(s_0,1)$ with $s_0 = 1/e = 0.3679\cdots$
Then, indeed, there are two solutions (one more than trivial one) for $s\in (0,s_0) \cup (s_0,1)$. Which, for the original problem, implies that there are two solutions, one in each side of the intervals $(0,1)$ $(1,e)$.
